# convexity of a function of 2 variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $|f|$ is convex.

Prove that $F\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $F(x,y)=|f(x)|+|y-f(x)|$ is convex.

Comment: what have you done ?

Comment: I started checking by the convexity condition and I did some particular cases, but I think there should be another method